# How to detect import statements errors as early as possible in ES6?

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

Let's say I create a class like this in `my-class.js`:

```
class MyClass {
    someMethod() {}
}

export { MyClass }
```

And I then incorrectly import it like this:

```
import MyClass from 'my-class.js'

// Should actually be: import { MyClass } from 'my-class.js'
```

Then later when I try to do `new MyClass()`, it's going to throw an obscure error such as `TypeError: _MyClass.default is not a constructor`. There are other similar cases like this when an incorrect import leads to strange errors.

So I'm wondering, is there any way to catch early this kind of import errors?

Comment: No, not natively. Plus it has no idea what you're exporting or importing beforehand, only at runtime.

Comment: The exporting class does not get to participate in what was imported so you can't detected it from the class definition or from the imported file.  So, any detection would have to be done on the `import` side of things at runtime.  Short of creating a function that does the import and type checking imported values, I don't see what else you can do unless you want to write manual type checking on each import.  If you use TypeScript, it would tell you if you had a type mismatch between the imported value and the declared variable.

Comment: Are you looking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import?

Comment: This type of error is possible to catch at compile-time with [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). Just rename your `.js` files to `.ts` and `.jsx` to `.tsx`. You can see [my boilerplate](https://github.com/styfle/react-server-example-tsx/blob/master/src/server.tsx#L7) for a working example.